# Simple jQuery .load Example Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is a fairly basic question, but I'm relatively new to jQuery so was hoping someone might be able to help.

Basically, I need to load an HTML snippet into a page. This works fine when the snippet contains just HTML, but not when it contains a script.

I've stripped down my code to the bare minimum for clarity. This is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div id="banner"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner').load('banner.html');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And banner.html contains just the following (as an example):

```
<h2>Subheading</h2>
<script>
document.write('Hello');
</script>
```

The script is executed, but for some reason it strips out the rest of the HTML in both index.html and banner.html (i.e. it just displays "Hello" and nothing else).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.write` after the page has load writes to the document, and at the same overwrites everything else currently in the document, that's why you end up with only the string "hello".

Just remove the document write :

```
<h2>Subheading</h2>
<p id="test"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'hello';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is becuase when banner.html is loaded .. the script inside banner.html get executed, which writes "hello" in your document(the document  here is your entire index.html)

one way to understand this is by replacing certain content of banner.html rather than the whole document.

**banner.html**

```
<h2>Subheading</h2>
<div id="divID"></div>
<script>
  $('#divID').html('hello');  //using jquery .. gets the element with id as divID and replace the HTML 
 </script>
```

here i am replacing just the div whose id is "divID" rather than replacing the enrite document